# video encoding trans-coding in c#

Tags: c#, video, encoding, transcoding

I am allowing users to upload video files in various formats, such as:  .avi, .mpg, .mpeg, .flv, .mov, .m2v, .m4v, .mp4, .rm, .ram, .vob, .wmv, .bin ... My only restriction so far is file size up to max 512Mb.
Evidently, some of the files are HD and extremely large. 
I wish to compress all files transcoding them into a web friendly compressed file type such as h.264 mp4  files to be streamed back through my video player. I am using JWPlayer.

Do you know of a decent, easy to implement, c# library, that will help me trans-code those files into a standard compressed type to be streamed back ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For a C# library your options may be more limited.  What about external tools you can run as separate processes?  Like ffdshow for example.

Comment: You may want to look at FFMpeg or Amazon Elastic Transcoder which is basically FFMpeg as a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're looking for something like FFmpeg.
You can either call it by command line or you use a wrapper library like [FFmpeg C#](http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/)